# Detect unsaved data in datatable and prompt with confirm message on navigation

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I am using  primefaces datatable . If i do any changes in table and not saved the changes and if i try to navigate away from the screen we need to display warning message.

Answer (score 1):

Good idea by @Daniel, but I didn't like the expensive bind he has set on every input change. and what if your table had a drop down menu, or checkbox, or... ? you would have to bind a change event on them too.

Bind an `onchange` event on your `datatable` only, via `widgetVar` attribute.
set a `widgetVar` to your table for example `myTableVar`.
Then use this:

```
<script>
var dirtyFlag = false;

$(window).bind("beforeunload", function(event) {
    if(dirtyFlag === true) 
        return "You have unsaved changes";
});
myTableVar.tbody.context.onchange = function() {dirtyFlag = true;}
</script>
```

Comment: For a small code improve its more acceptable to add a comment to the original answer instead copy paste it in a new answer.

Comment: @Daniel apologies, no answer stealing is meant :) just wanted a more space to explain exactly what changed and why.
Also noted for the next times, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick an dirty solution, just drop it into your js file (you can test it online on [Primefaces Datatable Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowEditing.jsf;jsessionid=utoak7bpgu8wu669598oft44) in the browser console)

```
var dirtyFlag = false;

$(window).bind("beforeunload",function(event) {
    if(dirtyFlag === true) return "You have unsaved changes";
});

$(document).on('change','input', function(){dirtyFlag = true});
```

And don't forget to set your `dirtyFlag` to false after clicking on your save button

---

Regarding the selector for the change event: you can fine tune it to include other inputs under a certain form etc'